# Unity Container resolve calling same parameterized constructor twice

Tags: c#, .net, dependency-injection, unity-container

I'm using a unity container and I'm trying to resolve by passing the object to the parameterized constructor, I noticed the same constructor is called twice, the first time it takes appropriate values, and not sure why it is calling again and it overrides with a blank object, can someone help me what is happening over here, not able to solve it.

```
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    
     if (container == null)
        {
            container = new UnityContainer().AddExtension(new Diagnostic());
            container.RegisterType<ISubscribeService,OOrderProc.Common.SubscribeService.SubscribeService>();                
            container.RegisterType<IBaseOrderProcessing, BaseSubscribe>("Subscribe");                
        }
        SubscribeDetails m = new SubscribeDetails();
        m.SubscribeType = SubscribeType.ACTIVATE;
        m.SubscribeName = "TEST";

       var b = container.Resolve<IBaseOrderProcessing>("Subscribe",new DependencyOverride<BaseSubscribe>(new OOrderProc.Common.SubscribeService.SubscribeService(m)));
    //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////



    public interface IBaseOrderProcessing
            {
                void ProcessOrder();
            }
    
        
    
     public interface ISubscribeService
        {
            SubscribeType SubscribeType { get; set; }
            void ActivateSubscribe();
    
            void UpgradeSubscribe();
        }
        
        // Strategy Pattern 1  => Subscribe is one of the "if" condition
        public class BaseSubscribe : IBaseOrderProcessing
        {
            private ISubscribeService _SubscribeService = null;
            public BaseSubscribe(ISubscribeService SubscribeService)
            {
                _SubscribeService = SubscribeService;
            }
            
            public void ProcessOrder()
            {
                if (_SubscribeService.SubscribeType == SubscribeType.ACTIVATE)
                    _SubscribeService.ActivateSubscription();
    
                if (_SubscribeService.SubscribeType == SubscribeType.UPGRADE)
                    _SubscribeService.UpgradeSubscription();
                
            }
        }
    
    // Writing another class to simplify is correct ?????
     public class SubscribeService : ISubscribeService
        {
            private SubscribeDetails _Subscribedetails = null;
    
            public SubscribeType SubscribeType { get; set; }
    
            public SubscribeService(SubscribeDetails Subscribedetails)
            {
                _Subscribedetails = Subscribedetails;
                SubscribeType = Subscribedetails.SubscribeType;
            }
            public void ActivateSubscription()
            {
                // Code to save the Subscribe details in the database
                Console.WriteLine($"\n\nSubscribe {_Subscribedetails.SubscribeId} for {_Subscribedetails.SubscribeName} activated for order Id: {_Subscribedetails.OrderId}" +
                    $" from {_Subscribedetails.SubscribeStartDate} to {_Subscribedetails.SubscribeEndDate}");        
            }      
    
            public void UpgradeSubscription()
            {
                // Code to upgrade the Subscribe details in the database
                Console.WriteLine($"\n\nSubscribe {_Subscribedetails.SubscribeId} for {_Subscribedetails.SubscribeName} upgraded for order Id: {_Subscribedetails.OrderId}" +
                    $" from {_Subscribedetails.SubscribeStartDate} to {_Subscribedetails.SubscribeEndDate}");
    
            }
        }
```

Comment: Why does BaseOrderProcessing implement IBaseOrderProcessing but also take in an IBaseOrderProcessing as part of the constructor? That makes no sense.

Comment: @mason Thanks for pointing that out, I wished to use it for some purpose but seems useless, I'm implementing strategic pattern, could you help me to understand if it's correct and my base question how can implement DI using unity?

Comment: BaseOrderProcessing looks useless. Just get rid of it. Then what problem do you have once that's done?

Comment: @mason  Yes I have got rid of that but still the child constructor is called twice if I try to resolve using unity

Comment: @mason I have edited my question, you can have a look the code inside "///"

Answer (score -1):

I resolved using below code:

```
container.RegisterType<IBaseOrderProcessing, BaseSubscribe>("Subscribe", new InjectionConstructor(new OOrderProc.Common.SubscribeService.SubscribeService((SubscribeDetails)obj)));
                    return container.Resolve<IBaseOrderProcessing>("Subscribe");
```

Comment: Why are you using named registrations and InjectionConstructor? You might as well not even be using Unity if you're going to do that. Instead, let Unity resolve the dependencies for each service. Watch [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1PDO-VALRao) which will explain the basics of DI.